# How to retrieve url from firebase database and show url as a image in imageview (SWIFT)?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

**I m trying to get Url of image from firebase database and show that url as a image in imageview (iOS).**

**below is the image of database**

[image: firebase database screenshot]

**How can I do so? 
I just started with Xcode, any help will be much appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func showImage() {

    Database.database().reference().child("Images").child("abcd").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let url = snapshot.value as? String {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
                if error == nil {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    imageView.image = image
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but it takes too much time to get downloaded. Is there any way to speed up the process and display it faster than at present?

Comment: No, this is the shortest and the fastest way to do it. Actually in this case observeSingleEvent should execute fast (it downloads only one string), but URLSession.shared.dataTask may execute slow because the size of image can be large.

Comment: So you should hold an image with smaller size. This should help.

Comment: Ok will try to make image size smaller. Firebase offline can be helpful in speeding up images?

Comment: I don't have an experience with Firebase offline, but i know that it provides tools for persisting data locally. So, when network interrupts you can use all cached data that was previously downloaded. So while offline you can retrieve url via observeSingleEvent and it will give you result only if you have previously get this url while online. But in any case you have to download image from url and image may store in Storage. Storage can't handle disk persistence for you, only Database. So, I think this will not help you.

Comment: Okay. So, i got only one way and that is to make image size smaller as much as possible. Will work in this direction. Thanks a lot for helping me out.